# its there a way to use eslint disable in the settings json?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Im using in some files /* eslint disable */ but i think this may be unecessary, there's a way i can use in all files using settings.json?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLIXN.png)

Comment: If you are looking to disable ESLint in all your files, then why not disable the extension outright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your Options for Disabling an Extension in VS-Code

To disable the extension open up the extension menu in the **Activity-Bar. Locate the extension you wish to disable, and then click the gear to the right of that extension. When you click the gear button, a menu will open, it will have several options — 2 of the options in the middle of the menu will offer you to disable the extension:

1. The first option disables the extension globally.
2. The second option will be to disable the extension for your current workspace.

Afterwards you need to restart your browser.

---

#### One more option

To disable all of your installed extensions, use the Disable All Installed Extensions command. To do this hit F1 to open the quick menu, it should drop open from the top of your screen. Once open type **"Disable All Installed Extensions"** into the Command Palette and select the `Disable All Installed Extensions` option once it appears.

---

###### Below is a screen shot I cropped to demonstrate disabling an extension:

[image: Disable VS-Code Extension]

---

**SIDE-NOTE:** *A disabled extension will need to be enabled, when the user decides to use it. If you don not plan on using the extension in the foreseeable future, you should just remove the extension rather than permanently disabling the extension.*

###### [FOR MORE HELP AND INFO VISIT:](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_disable-an-extension)

###### https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_disable-an-extension